# iTunes: How to transfer a music purchase between two Apple IDs?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, music, itunes-store

I bought an album off of iTunes on my phone, and now my mom wants to listen to it. The problem is I bought the songs using my apple ID on my phone, and her iTunes is under a different account.

**Q: Is it possible to put the music on her account** even though I bought it with a different apple ID? If so, how?

Comment: Sadly, no. It's not possible. You can, however, apply for an Apple Music Family Plan and share songs this way. It's, however, very different, because it wouldn't be the music you bought anymore, but streamable files instead.

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

No, purchases can not be transferred between Apple IDs.

---

### Alternative 1: Return/buy again

If you intended to use your mother's account to buy the album you may try to return the item using iTunes on your computer (Store > My Account...).

In case that you get a refund you can buy the album using the other Apple ID.

---

### Alternative 2: [iCloud Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/)

If you set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088) you are able to download purchases made by other members of your family that are a part of Family Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, it's not possible to transfer music between Apple ID's, but other than family sharing or just logging in on your Apple ID on your mother's iMac, you could also try to just download the music on a computer and copy the files to your mother's iTunes library, since music brought on iTunes is now [drm-free](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201616).

I would recommend Family Sharing though.