# Export / import Apple Music collection between different AppleIDs

Tags: music, apple-music

Is there a way to export / import Apple Music library from one account to another?

I have used Apple Music with one account and have a lot of albums added to my collection. Now I have changed my account to another and search for way to transfer my music library to new account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iTunes: How to transfer a music purchase between two Apple IDs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284859/itunes-how-to-transfer-a-music-purchase-between-two-apple-ids)

Comment: No, my question not about purchased music, but about Apple Music subscription. There is online services (like soundiiz) which solve my problem, but I am looking form offline solution.

Comment: When you subscribe, you’re “renting” the music.  You can share your library, but you can’t export anything.  You can copy over your playlist, but not the library.   If you’re moving to a new AppleID, you must start from scratch.

Comment: @Allan, I can export names (and IDs) of albums in my library. And I am looking for solution which can add this albums back to my collection using this IDs (names).

Comment: Create a playlist and add from there.  See if that works.